# Roots are the reciprocal of $f(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

[image]

I don't understand if $f(x)$ has roots, $r_1, r_2$ for example and $g(x)$ has roots $\frac{1}{r_1}, \frac{1}{r_2}$

Then how is $g(x) = x^2f(\frac{1}{x})$

What does $$f(\frac{1}{x})$$ have to do with this?

Answer (score 1):

For a given polynomial $f$ with roots $r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_n$ there exists a function $g$ with roots $\frac 1{r_1},\frac 1{r_2},\ldots,\frac 1{r_n}$. The solution you cite points out that $f\left(\frac 1x\right)$ is one such $g$, since the required property of $g$ is that $g\left(\frac 1{r_j}\right)=0$ for a root of $f$ $r_j$, and $f\left(\frac 1{1/r_j}\right)=f(r_j)=0$ satisfies this property. I don't see any reference to $g(x)=x^2f\left(\frac 1x\right)$, although this works too.

Comment: $g$ actually does not have a root at $x=0$ because $f(1/x) \to \pm \infty$ for $x \to 0$ given that $r_i \neq 0$ for all $i$

Comment: Good point, edited.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ has roots $r_1, r_2$ and we assume that $f$ is of degree $2$, that is 
$$f(x) = ax^2 + bx+ c,$$
then
$$g(x) := f\left( \frac{1}{x} \right) = a \frac{1}{x^2} + b\frac{1}{x} + c$$
has the roots $1/r_1,1/r_2$, because - as stated in the solution - we have
$$g(1/r_1) = f(\frac{1}{1/r_1}) = f(r_1) =0.$$
That is all good but $g$ obviously is no polynomial. So, in order to 'fix' this, we simply multiply by the highest power of $x$ that occurs in $f$. In this example it is $x^2$:
$$h(x) := x^2 \cdot g(x) = x^2 \cdot \left(a \frac{1}{x^2} + b\frac{1}{x} + c \right) = a + bx + cx^2$$
Now this new polynomial $h$ has the roots $1/r_1,1/r_2$ because
$$h(1/r_1) = \left(\frac{1}{r_1}\right)^2 \cdot g(1/r_1) =  \left(\frac{1}{r_1}\right)^2 \cdot 0 = 0 $$

I hope this helps you to solve the original Example 6-11.

Comment: Note the pretty interesting fact that this is the same as reversing the order or all the coefficients.